# How to set a colour ratio in different sectors and manipulate it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Please see picture 1: I am trying to make a colour scale in the picture for example the picture right now is red/orange colour in the background is 1:0 (orange background:white dots), and if the ration is 0.8:0.2 then the background would be a bit more faint and the colour in the dots will be bit more orange.

Is this possible in Illustrator, Photoshop or ImageJ?

Please help, many thanks in advance.
[image: Picture 1]

Comment: Is this several layers or a flattened image of the dots?

Comment: Remember the monitor is not linear

Comment: The dots are a different layer. This is in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seeing as I can't even think of a way to do it with a flattened image, start with your layer as a background and draw the ellipses on a new layer. 
We also need a third layer as a white canvas to have behind

The we can go to Layer > Layer Style > Colour Overlay and add our orange colour to our background. You wanted a ratio of .8:.02 so let's make it 80% opacity.

[image]

You can then do the exact same for the ellipses but make the opacity on them 20%. 
Here's what it'll look like.

[image]